# Facebook Graph API results retrieving

Tags: objective-c, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When we use Graph API in Facebook the results come in the following format. Is there a convenient class built to retrieve them in iPhone?

JSON parser?

```
{
    "type": "audiotrack"
    "name": "Without Me - Eminem",
    "metadata": {
        "trackinfo": {
            "title":  "Without Me",
            "artist": "Eminem",
            "album":  "Curtain Call - The Hits"
        }
        "trackdata": {
            "kind":       "MPEG",
            "size":       "6.3 MB",
            "bitrate":    "179 kbps",
            "samplerate": "44.100 khz",
            "released":   "14400",
            "formato:     "MPEG-1, Layer 3",
            "channels":   "Joint Stereo",
            "id3tag":     "v2.3",
            "encodedby":  "LAME 3.90"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in *[Tutorial: JSON Over HTTP On The iPhone](http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/)*.